# How to find values and use their subtraction in a search/replace with a perl script

Tags: regex, perl

I need to get values from lines like `<fpage>327</fpage>` and `<lpage>335</lpage>` and use their difference to replace `NaN`in a line with `<page-count count="NaN"/>`.

**sample input file:**

```
...many lines
<volume>74</volume>
<issue>3</issue>
<fpage>327</fpage>
<lpage>335</lpage>
...many lines
<counts><fig-count count="3"/><table-count count="2"/><equation-count count="0"/><ref-count count="37"/><page-count count="0"/></counts>
...many lines
```

**sample output file desired:**

```
...many lines
<volume>74</volume>
<issue>3</issue>
<fpage>327</fpage>
<lpage>335</lpage>
...many lines
<counts><fig-count count="3"/><table-count count="2"/><equation-count count="0"/><ref-count count="37"/><page-count count="8"/></counts>
...many lines
```

**Here is what I am trying but I am getting `<page-count count="0"/>`:**

```perl
while ( <$input> ) {
    my $fpage = $1 if $fpage =~ m/<fpage>(\d+)/;
    my $lpage = $1 if $lpage =~ m/<lpage>(\d+)/;
    my $pages = $lpage - $fpage;
    $_ =~ s!<page-count count="NaN"/>!<page-count count="${pages}"/>!;

    print {$output} $_;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually testing the input for fpage and lpage. Try something like:

```
while ( my $in = <$input> ) {
    my $fpage = $1 if $in =~ /<fpage>(\d+)/;
    my $lpage = $1 if $in =~ /<lpage>(\d+)/;
    my $pages = $lpage - $fpage;
    $in =~ s!<page-count count="NaN"/>!<page-count count="${pages}"/>!;

    print {$output} $in;
}
```

Note: This will only work if the entire block of text you're matching and replacing is available in each iteration of the `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks, I just had to put 'local $/ = undef;` before the `while` to treat all in one go and it works!

Comment: @Luciano: I'm sure you are wrong. With that change in place your program would replace only the first occurrence of `<page-count count="NaN"/>`

Answer (score 0):

1)   Your variables `$fpage` and `$lpage` go out of scope on each iteration.  You can extend the scope by moving their decleration outsidde the while loop.

2)   `=~` does not do what you seem to want it to do.  the command `$fpage =~ m/<fpage>(\d+)/` is telling the Regex to search inside the variable `$fpage`.  The default variable to search is `$_`, so your use of `$_ =~` is redundant (and bad style)

3)   If `NaN` occurs multiple times, your current code would only catch the first occurence.

```
my $fpage;
my $lpage;
while ( <$input> ) {
    $fpage = $1 if $fpage =~ m/<fpage>(\d+)/;
    $lpage = $1 if $lpage =~ m/<lpage>(\d+)/;
    my $pages = $lpage - $fpage;
    s!<page-count count="NaN"/>!<page-count count="${pages}"/>!;

    print {$output} $_;
}
```

This performs no checks that you actually find fpage and lpage before the page-count.